# Webpack: load module outside the project

Tags: lambda, webpack, apex-framework

I'm using webpack on the server with AWS Lambda and Apex. The webpack config is relative to the functions which are included in a project. So the structure is like this

- Apex project

  - functions
  - myFunction
    -src
    index.js // lambda function
  - shared
  - package.json
  - project.json
  - webpack.config.js

Here is my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: './lib',
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: [/node_modules/]
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve('../../shared'),
      'node_modules'
    ]
  }
}
```

in my myFunction/src/index.js I'm trying to include my shared module:

```
import {myModule} from 'my-module.js';
```

When I build, the shared directory or it's modules are never included. I don't want to change the root because this setup allows me to easily add function directories. I need a way to add the shared directory when I import custom modules. I also tried relative paths insteal of the resolve config with:

```
import {myModule} from '../../shared/my-module.js';
```